# Angular 2 survey app

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to make a survey app that asks questions and the user can click on circles for their answers. It has to be done in such a way that only 1 circle can be filled (i.e. with color) at a time. So if there was a question asking "what is your favorite color", it could have blue and red as options. User clicks blue and the circle for that option becomes gray for example. User then clicks red which removes the highlighting from blue's circle and then the app gets the circle for red highlighted.

Every one of these circles must be a component. I've made them easily, but making the circle-filling part I specified above is proving to be a challenge. I will post parts of my components here. I'm new to angular 2, so sorry for any syntactical/logical mistakes.

Main app component file:

```
<div>
<p style="font-size: 23px;">What is your favorite color?</p>
<app-fave-color-red></app-fave-color-red>
<app-fave-color-green></app-fave-color-green>
<app-fave-color-blue></app-fave-color-blue>
<app-fave-color-other></app-fave-color-other>
</div>
```

and this one is the "fave-color-red" component html

```
<div>
<div class="circle" *ngIf="isCircle" (click)="changeToGray()"></div>
<div class="filledCircle" *ngIf="!isFilled" (click)="changeToGray()"></div>
<p> &nbsp; Red </p>
</div>
```

this is the .ts file for fave color red component

```
isFilled = true;
isCircle = true;

changeToGray() {
  if (this.isFilled == true) {
  this.isCircle = false;
  this.isFilled = false;
} else if (this.isFilled == false) {
  this.isCircle = true;
  this.isFilled = true;
}
}
```

basically i'm switching the empty circle div with a filled circle div for red, blue, etc. User can deselect the circles, as well.

I just don't know the logic for making sure only one of the circles for each question can be filled. I think i have to do something in my main app.component file but i'm not sure what.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you considered radio buttons?

Comment: yes but i want to use divs since they're more customizable

Comment: Why not use svg icons